# How to reliably retrieve a window's background color on macOS with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Is there a Swifty way to detect the background color of a window in SwiftUI on macOS, that would work reliably regardless of the current theme (Dark Mode or Light Mode)?

For example, if one were to make a solid rectangle that "blends in" with the window's background, which color would they use?

This answer suggests the use of `NSColor.xxxBackgroundColor`:
[SwiftUI: Get the Dynamic Background Color (Dark Mode or Light Mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60672626/swiftui-get-the-dynamic-background-color-dark-mode-or-light-mode)

However, this doesn't quite work for me. Here's some test code (Xcode 12.5, Swift 5.4) that makes three rectangles of various `NSColor`s. I am looking for the one that blends in with the background.

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("This text is on the default background")
            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                Text("windowBackgroundColor")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                    .background(Color(NSColor.windowBackgroundColor))
                Text("underPageBackgroundColor")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                    .background(Color(NSColor.underPageBackgroundColor))
                Text("textBackgroundColor")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                    .background(Color(NSColor.textBackgroundColor))
            }
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
}
```

In Dark mode, it seems `NSColor.underPageBackgroundColor` matches the window's background.
[image]

But in Light mode, nothing matches:
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the colors provided by the background or to check the the theme? Your question isn't very clear and I'm not 100% sure my answer is even in the right area.

Comment: @xTwisteDx Indeed looking for the color provided by the background of the window. Let me see if I can clarify the question.

Comment: I guess what Im asking is, what do you want to do with those colors? From my perspective it appears you already have the colors, so do what you want with them. I feel like you need to explain what your expected outcome is. It looks like you've already reliably fetched the colors you're looking for.

Comment: Ahh now I see. You'll need to set that color, otherwise it's not going to appear as you expect. There's no way to "Get" a color from a view, you can however set the color. I'm updating my answer now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Swifty way to get Window Background

The window's background is not composed by a color, is a `NSVisualEffectView` with `.windowBackground` as `material`.

You can achieve that with this code:

```
struct EffectView: NSViewRepresentable {
    @State var material: NSVisualEffectView.Material = .headerView
    @State var blendingMode: NSVisualEffectView.BlendingMode = .withinWindow

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSVisualEffectView {
        let view = NSVisualEffectView()
        view.material = material
        view.blendingMode = blendingMode
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        nsView.material = material
        nsView.blendingMode = blendingMode
    }
}
```

And apply that to your view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        EffectView(material: .windowBackground)
            .overlay(Text("Window Real Background"))
            .padding(30)
    }
}
```

The output is this (nothing to see because it mimetizes with background):

[image]

The reason why the background is an NSVisualEffectView is because the Window Tinting of macOS Big Sur, that changes the background according to wallpaper predominant color:

[image]

Comment: Thing of beauty! Indeed with `.windowBackground` as material I can use the EffectView as a background and get exactly the effect I was looking for. Thanks for the underlying explanation.

Comment: super cool, guessing there's no way to convert this into a NSColor to be able to put it in a SCNScene which expects a NSColor like `scene.background.contents = CPColor.primaryBackground` ?

Comment: You can always use this view as a background ie: `MyView().background(EffectView(material: .windowBackground))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Environment` variables to get the ColorScheme that is being produced. In iOS I often use it like this, however it should translate to MacOS as well. There is no way to GET a view's color dynamically, because it is a set value that is not accessible. The best you can do is set the view, in a known state, and then pass that color around as needed. In my example I just used `Color.black and Color.white` but you can easily assign any color to a variable and pass it around so that it is known.

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

struct TestView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("This text is on the default background")
            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                Text("windowBackgroundColor")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                    .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
                Text("underPageBackgroundColor")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                    .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
                Text("textBackgroundColor")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                    .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
            }
        }
        .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
        .padding(20)
    }
}
```

In your case you can alternate the colors to the system colors that you're wanting to use. Setting based on the `colorScheme` for the particular color you want on that view. Eg...

```
var windowBGColor = NSColor.windowBackgroundColor
var underPageBGColor = NSColor.underPageBackgroundColor
var textBGColor = NSColor.textBackgroundColor

var sampleColor = colorScheme == .dark ? windowBGColor : textBGColor
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the workaround I've used to make things work (i.e. set the background color on the window to a known value that kinda works with the current color scheme) but I was hoping to find a more reliable way to know the actual color used at runtime to make things more future proof. It really feels [NSColor.windowBackroundColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1528630-windowbackgroundcolor) should have been it.

Answer (score 0):

The `windowBackground` is a real window's background color, you just compare it not with real window background, but with theme view below hosting controller view

Here is a hierarchy (you can verify it yourself in view debug mode)

[image: demo]

Comment: This made me discover the view debugger which is super helpful, thanks for that.